# How to install ia32-libs in Debian Wheezy?

Tags: debian, 32bit

I would like to install `ia32-libs` in Debian Wheezy however it seems it is deprecated. The solution in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/76146/unable-to-install-ia32-libs-in-debian-wheezy) works when installing 32-bit packages from Debian repositories, but there are some external applications I would like to install (in `/opt/`) that are 32-bit.

Is there a way to force-install `ia32-libs`?

Comment: The method in my answer there should still work. `libc6:i386` should provide many of the same files as `ia32-libs`.`ldd /opt/<yourbinary>` will show you which files you need.

Comment: The last part of your comment is what I was missing, thanks! Care to post it as an answer so I can accept it?

Comment: Debian Wheezy is multilib capable (although this is disabled per default). I don't remember by heart how to enable the 32bit architecture, but you can install the wine package (which is just a placeholder, since wine requires 32bit) and then run the installed wine "application", which will display instructions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Luckily Wheezy don't need `ia32-libs` any more. Instead one might enable "i386" architecture using

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

and then (after `sudo apt-get update`) install 32-bit libraries using `apt-get` like in the following example:

```
sudo apt-get install libgl1-mesa-glx:i386
```