# How to use both 32 bits and 64 bits Java on Debian?

Tags: debian, java, firefox, plugin, iceweasel

I am running Linux Mint LMDE on a 64 bits machine.
I have installed OpenJDK 64bits: 7u21-2.3.9-5 which is used by some applications.
IceWeasel has Iced-Tea 1.3.2 plugin installed (64bits).

Now I want to use some web meeting services such as Webex or Yugma. But these services require Java 32 bits support. They don't work with 64 bits Java.

I tried to install the Java 32 bits version from Oracle web site, but whatever Java -version always returns this:

> java version "1.7.0_21"
>
> OpenJDK Runtime Environment (IcedTea 2.3.9)
>
> (7u21-2.3.9-5) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)

Is it possible to have both 32 bits and 64 bits of Java on one machine?

How to install and select the versions?

How to swap 32 bits and 64 bits plugins in Iceweasel?

Comment: Can you use the free version of Java? openjdk should be available for debian for both 32 and 64 bit. See for example http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/84481/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Debian openjdk packages are marked `Multi-Arch: same` so you should be able to do:

- sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
- sudo apt-get update
- sudo apt-get install icedtea-6-plugin

You might need to remove the amd64 version of the browser plugin first, but you can have both versions of java itself installed at the same time.

Comment: OK, I now have icedtea-6-plugin:i386 installed. But it does not show up in Iceweasel, which is 64 bits. Shall I continue in downgrading my system and install 32bits version of Iceweasel if it exists ?

Comment: @user1185081 oh, yikes, you probably do have to. That's not cool. This is why we say to avoid proprietary software, its quality is terrible and there's no way to fix it.